# Asynchronous download in python not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, aiohttp, python-aiofiles

I am trying to implement a fast downloader in python.I am having an error when using aiofiles

```
async with aiofiles.open(pathlib.Path(self.__dest_path / filename).resolve(), 'wb') as fd:
                    for chunk in await response.content.read(self.__chunk_size):
                        if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                            await fd.write(chunk)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Khav\PycharmProjects\AsyncDownloaderTest\AsyncDownloader.py", line 119, in fetch_content
    await fd.write(chunk)
  File "C:\Users\Khav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\aiofiles\threadpool\utils.py", line 36, in method
    return (yield from self._loop.run_in_executor(self._executor, cb))
  File "C:\Users\Khav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<AsyncDownloader.fetch_content() done, defined at C:\Users\Khav\PycharmProjects\AsyncDownloaderTest\AsyncDownloader.py:105> exception=TypeError("a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'",)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Khav\PycharmProjects\AsyncDownloaderTest\AsyncDownloader.py", line 119, in fetch_content
    await fd.write(chunk)
  File "C:\Users\Khav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\aiofiles\threadpool\utils.py", line 36, in method
    return (yield from self._loop.run_in_executor(self._executor, cb))
  File "C:\Users\Khav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

Full code

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import pathlib
import fire
from aiohttp.resolver import AsyncResolver
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import aiofiles
from timeit import default_timer as timer


class AsyncDownloader:
    """Download files asynchronously"""

    __urls = set()
    __dest_path = None
    __user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0'
    __read_timeout = 60
    __connection_timeout = 30
    __download_count = 0  # unlimited
    # http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network
    __worker_count = 5  # No of threads to spawn
    __chunk_size = 512
    __download_time = -1
    __errors = []
    __success_urls = []

    # TODO Fetch only content of a specific type from a csv
    # TODO Improve code structure so that it can be used as a commandline tool (done)
    # https://dbader.org/blog/python-commandline-tools-with-click
    # https://github.com/google/python-fire

    def set_source_csv(self, source_path, column_name):
        self.source_path = source_path
        self.column_name = column_name

        try:
            my_csv = pd.read_csv(source_path, usecols=[self.column_name], chunksize=10)
        except ValueError:
            print("The column name doesn't exist")
            return self
        else:
            # No exception whatsoever
            for chunk in my_csv:
                self.__urls.update(set(getattr(chunk, self.column_name)))
        return self

    def set_destination_path(self, dest_path):
        if dest_path.endswith('/'):
            dest_path = dest_path[:-1]
        self.dest_path = dest_path
        # TODO Add exception in case we can't create the directory
        pathlib.Path(self.dest_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        if os.access(self.dest_path, os.W_OK):
            self.__dest_path = pathlib.Path(self.dest_path).resolve()
        return self

    def set_user_agent(self, useragent):
        self.useragent = useragent
        self.__user_agent = self.useragent
        return self

    def set_connection_timeout(self, ctimeout_secs):
        self.timeout_secs = ctimeout_secs
        if self.timeout_secs >= 0:
            self.__connection_timeout = self.timeout_secs
        return self

    def set_read_timeout(self, rtimeout_secs):
        self.timeout_secs = rtimeout_secs
        if self.timeout_secs >= 0:
            self.__read_timeout = self.timeout_secs
        return self

    def set_download_count(self, file_count):
        self.file_count = file_count
        if self.file_count > 0:
            self.__download_count = self.file_count
        return self

    def set_worker_count(self, worker_count):
        self.worker_count = worker_count
        if self.worker_count > 0:
            self.__worker_count = self.worker_count
        return self

    def set_chunk_size(self, chunk_size):
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size
        if self.chunk_size > 0:
            self.__chunk_size = self.chunk_size
        return self

    def print_urls(self):
        print(self.__urls)
        return self

    def get_download_time_secs(self):
        print(self.__download_time)
        return self

    def get_errors(self):
        print(self.__errors)
        return self

    async def fetch_content(self, url):
        headers = {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36'}
        resolver = AsyncResolver(nameservers=["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"])
        conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=self.__worker_count, ttl_dns_cache=300, verify_ssl=False)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn,
                                         read_timeout=self.__read_timeout,
                                         conn_timeout=self.__connection_timeout) as session:
            async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    filename = os.path.basename(str(response.url))
                    async with aiofiles.open(pathlib.Path(self.__dest_path / filename).resolve(), 'wb') as fd:
                        for chunk in await response.content.read(self.__chunk_size):
                            if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                                await fd.write(chunk)

    def download(self):

        if not pathlib.Path(self.__dest_path).exists():
            return "OS error : Directory to save file is not defined or does not exist"

        # Give an accurate file count even if we don't have to download it as it already exist
        file_count = 0

        urls_to_download = []

        for url in self.__urls:
            filename = os.path.basename(url)
            # check if we need only a limited number of files
            if self.__download_count != 0:
                if file_count < self.__download_count:
                    # No need to download file if it already exist
                    if pathlib.Path(self.__dest_path / filename).is_file():
                        file_count += 1
                        continue
                    else:
                        file_count += 1
                        urls_to_download.append(url)
            else:
                # Download all urls
                if not pathlib.Path(self.__dest_path / filename).is_file():
                    urls_to_download.append(url)

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        tasks = []
        for url in urls_to_download:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.fetch_content(url))
            tasks.append(task)
        start = timer()
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(0.250))  # for ssl connection
        loop.close()
        end = timer()
        self.__download_time = end - start

    def help(self):
        """Usage will go here"""
        print("This is help section")
        return self


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire(AsyncDownloader)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can loop on response.content.read return value I guess you are looping on the chunk there no?  Maybe something like that would work

`chunk = await response.content.read(self.__chunk_size)
While chunk:
    await fd.write(chunk)
    chunk = await response.content.read(self.__chunk_size)`